# Postgres Translate column value into schema prefix in a query

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that uses postgresql schemas for multi-tenancy purposes. It has a table in the `public` schema called `customers` with an `id` and `tenant` column. The value for tenant is a string, and there's a corresponding postgresql schema with tables in it that match.

It looks like this:

```
# public.customers  # first.users    # second.users
| id | tenant |     | id | name   |  | id | name   |
|----|--------|     |----|--------|  |----|--------|
| 1  | first  |     | 1  | bob    |  | 1  | jen    |
| 2  | second |     | 2  | jess   |  | 2  | mike   |
```

I'm wondering how I could make a single query to fetch values from a table in the schema, just given a customer id.

So if I have a customer_id of `1`, how can I `select * from first.users` in a single query.

I'm guessing this might have to be a function written in pgpsql, but I don't have a lot of experience with that. Something like:

```
select * from tenant_table(1, 'users');
```

?

Comment: are there any FK between relations?..

Comment: no FK........ no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace function f(_id int)
returns table (id int, name text) as $f$
declare _tenant text;
begin;

    select tenant into _tenant
    from public.customers
    where id = _id;

    return query execute format($e$
        select *
        from %I.users
    $e$, _tenant);
end;

$f$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with a single query.

You'll have to use one query that selects the schema name, then construct a second query and run that.

Of course you can define a PL/pgSQL function that does both for you and executes the dynamic query with `EXECUTE`.